# MongoDB createIndexes triggers operations while the indexes already exists

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, pymongo

I'm having an issue while trying to create indexes that already exists.
My scenario is that i have a service that every time it resets, it is trying to create indexes.
From what i’ve read on MongoDB documentation, it should not recreate it. When i tried it, i saw that our Mongo servers got lots of “CreateIndexes” commands when i issued db.currentOp() and it impacted the performance of our server. I wonder why it still tries to create the indexes and if there is something i can do to solve it? We are using python with pymongo to trigger the CreateIndexes command.

PS
When i saw the commands when used db.currentOp(), i saw that all of the commands had $truncated before them, couldn’t find something about it, what does it mean?

Tried to use createIndexes using pymongo